# Datagrid with grouping using first grouped row as a header

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, grouping, styles

I have a datagrid populated with some data. I bind to CollectionViewSource to specify group descriptions. I also override the group style to define the control template for the group header. 
Now I do not want to have the standard behavior with a group header with expander above the group item with grouped rows, but I want an expander on the first row of the group item and no header.

**Description:**
DataGridHeader: Last Name, First Name, Message
*X*: Expander
|: Cell separator

**A sample showing expanded data:**

```
    *X* | Smallboy | John  | Hello World
        | Smallboy | John  | Hello World Again
        | Smallboy | John  | Bye World

    *X* | Bigboy   | Billy | Hi everyone
        | Bigboy   | Billy | Bye everyone
```

**A sample showing collapsed data:**

```
*X* Smallboy John (3)
*X* Bigboy Billy (2)
```

Any help will be welcome!